# Redirecting traffic from overseas

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect

I have a UK only website and also a US website. How can I redirect traffic from overseas coming to the UK site and send it to the US site ?

My sites are written using VB and Asp.Net. I'm just learning it all but looking for a quick bit of code to do this if possible.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Your tags are self-contradictory: either you're using asp.net and vb.net, or asp-classic and vbscript, but it is impossible to use vb.net with asp-classic.

Comment: The usual issue is that they type asp, which is a synonym for asp-classic.  They usually mean asp.net as per the text